# Pause when mapping

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

I am mapping a function across a list, but would like to pause before each item.
For instance:

```
function[variable_]:=(
variable * 2
)
function/@{1,2,3}
```

would give me {2, 3, 6}

However, I would like for the function to pause before being mapped to the next variable, for instance, 1*2 (pause for let's say, 2 seconds), 2 *2 (pause for 2 seconds) 3 * 2 (pause for two seconds).

Is this at all possible?

Comment: There is a function called `Pause` that should do what you want. Just insert `Pause[2];` in the definition of you function.

Comment: Inserting `Pause` is probably not what you want. It will just increase the running time but you won't see how each element is calculated.

Comment: you can use `Print` or maybe work with `Monitor`. Its not really clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish,

Comment: I am curious about the motivation of the stated requirement, which somewhat appears strange to me.

Comment: This question first came up when I was using an API. The website suggested I do not abuse the API and limit my entries to once per 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
Function[{input}, 
  With[{output = function[input]}, 
   Print[{input, output}];
   Pause[1];
   output
  ]
] /@ {1,2,3}
```